# SVG animation logo

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have an SVG logo with two lines, one on top and the other on bottom.

I am trying to get both of the lines to expand from the middle all the way to the end.

https://codepen.io/christos_karol/pen/BaZzOmO?editors=1100

```css
.line3, .line2 {
  stroke-dasharray:2300;
    stroke-dashoffset:2300;
    animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {

  to {
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="324" height="51" viewBox="0 0 324 51" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path id="DENNIS PRESTON" d="M0.104 12.8H10.364C13.028 12.8 15.38 13.34 17.42 14.42C19.46 15.476 21.044 16.964 22.172 18.884C23.3 20.78 23.864 22.952 23.864 25.4C23.864 27.848 23.3 30.032 22.172 31.952C21.044 33.848 19.46 35.336 17.42 36.416C15.38 37.472 13.028 38 10.364 38H0.104V12.8ZM10.22 35.696C12.428 35.696 14.36 35.264 16.016 34.4C17.672 33.512 18.956 32.3 19.868 30.764C20.78 29.204 21.236 27.416 21.236 25.4C21.236 23.384 20.78 21.608 19.868 20.072C18.956 18.512 17.672 17.3 16.016 16.436C14.36 15.548 12.428 15.104 10.22 15.104H2.768V35.696H10.22ZM47.6662 35.696V38H29.8462V12.8H47.1262V15.104H32.5102V24.068H45.5422V26.336H32.5102V35.696H47.6662ZM74.9882 12.8V38H72.7922L56.5922 17.552V38H53.9282V12.8H56.1242L72.3602 33.248V12.8H74.9882ZM104.273 12.8V38H102.077L85.8774 17.552V38H83.2134V12.8H85.4094L101.645 33.248V12.8H104.273ZM112.499 12.8H115.163V38H112.499V12.8ZM130.31 38.216C128.438 38.216 126.638 37.916 124.91 37.316C123.206 36.716 121.886 35.924 120.95 34.94L121.994 32.888C122.906 33.8 124.118 34.544 125.63 35.12C127.142 35.672 128.702 35.948 130.31 35.948C132.566 35.948 134.258 35.54 135.386 34.724C136.514 33.884 137.078 32.804 137.078 31.484C137.078 30.476 136.766 29.672 136.142 29.072C135.542 28.472 134.798 28.016 133.91 27.704C133.022 27.368 131.786 27.008 130.202 26.624C128.306 26.144 126.794 25.688 125.666 25.256C124.538 24.8 123.566 24.116 122.75 23.204C121.958 22.292 121.562 21.056 121.562 19.496C121.562 18.224 121.898 17.072 122.57 16.04C123.242 14.984 124.274 14.144 125.666 13.52C127.058 12.896 128.786 12.584 130.85 12.584C132.29 12.584 133.694 12.788 135.062 13.196C136.454 13.58 137.654 14.12 138.662 14.816L137.762 16.94C136.706 16.244 135.578 15.728 134.378 15.392C133.178 15.032 132.002 14.852 130.85 14.852C128.642 14.852 126.974 15.284 125.846 16.148C124.742 16.988 124.19 18.08 124.19 19.424C124.19 20.432 124.49 21.248 125.09 21.872C125.714 22.472 126.482 22.94 127.394 23.276C128.33 23.588 129.578 23.936 131.138 24.32C132.986 24.776 134.474 25.232 135.602 25.688C136.754 26.12 137.726 26.792 138.518 27.704C139.31 28.592 139.706 29.804 139.706 31.34C139.706 32.612 139.358 33.776 138.662 34.832C137.99 35.864 136.946 36.692 135.53 37.316C134.114 37.916 132.374 38.216 130.31 38.216ZM164.364 12.8C167.58 12.8 170.1 13.568 171.924 15.104C173.748 16.64 174.66 18.752 174.66 21.44C174.66 24.128 173.748 26.24 171.924 27.776C170.1 29.288 167.58 30.044 164.364 30.044H157.596V38H154.932V12.8H164.364ZM164.292 27.704C166.788 27.704 168.696 27.164 170.016 26.084C171.336 24.98 171.996 23.432 171.996 21.44C171.996 19.4 171.336 17.84 170.016 16.76C168.696 15.656 166.788 15.104 164.292 15.104H157.596V27.704H164.292ZM197.628 38L191.868 29.9C191.22 29.972 190.548 30.008 189.852 30.008H183.084V38H180.42V12.8H189.852C193.068 12.8 195.588 13.568 197.412 15.104C199.236 16.64 200.148 18.752 200.148 21.44C200.148 23.408 199.644 25.076 198.636 26.444C197.652 27.788 196.236 28.76 194.388 29.36L200.544 38H197.628ZM189.78 27.74C192.276 27.74 194.184 27.188 195.504 26.084C196.824 24.98 197.484 23.432 197.484 21.44C197.484 19.4 196.824 17.84 195.504 16.76C194.184 15.656 192.276 15.104 189.78 15.104H183.084V27.74H189.78ZM224.256 35.696V38H206.436V12.8H223.716V15.104H209.1V24.068H222.132V26.336H209.1V35.696H224.256ZM237.466 38.216C235.594 38.216 233.794 37.916 232.066 37.316C230.362 36.716 229.042 35.924 228.106 34.94L229.15 32.888C230.062 33.8 231.274 34.544 232.786 35.12C234.298 35.672 235.858 35.948 237.466 35.948C239.722 35.948 241.414 35.54 242.542 34.724C243.67 33.884 244.234 32.804 244.234 31.484C244.234 30.476 243.922 29.672 243.298 29.072C242.698 28.472 241.954 28.016 241.066 27.704C240.178 27.368 238.942 27.008 237.358 26.624C235.462 26.144 233.95 25.688 232.822 25.256C231.694 24.8 230.722 24.116 229.906 23.204C229.114 22.292 228.718 21.056 228.718 19.496C228.718 18.224 229.054 17.072 229.726 16.04C230.398 14.984 231.43 14.144 232.822 13.52C234.214 12.896 235.942 12.584 238.006 12.584C239.446 12.584 240.85 12.788 242.218 13.196C243.61 13.58 244.81 14.12 245.818 14.816L244.918 16.94C243.862 16.244 242.734 15.728 241.534 15.392C240.334 15.032 239.158 14.852 238.006 14.852C235.798 14.852 234.13 15.284 233.002 16.148C231.898 16.988 231.346 18.08 231.346 19.424C231.346 20.432 231.646 21.248 232.246 21.872C232.87 22.472 233.638 22.94 234.55 23.276C235.486 23.588 236.734 23.936 238.294 24.32C240.142 24.776 241.63 25.232 242.758 25.688C243.91 26.12 244.882 26.792 245.674 27.704C246.466 28.592 246.862 29.804 246.862 31.34C246.862 32.612 246.514 33.776 245.818 34.832C245.146 35.864 244.102 36.692 242.686 37.316C241.27 37.916 239.53 38.216 237.466 38.216ZM257.211 15.104H248.355V12.8H268.731V15.104H259.875V38H257.211V15.104ZM283.651 38.216C281.155 38.216 278.887 37.664 276.847 36.56C274.831 35.432 273.247 33.896 272.095 31.952C270.967 30.008 270.403 27.824 270.403 25.4C270.403 22.976 270.967 20.792 272.095 18.848C273.247 16.904 274.831 15.38 276.847 14.276C278.887 13.148 281.155 12.584 283.651 12.584C286.147 12.584 288.391 13.136 290.383 14.24C292.399 15.344 293.983 16.88 295.135 18.848C296.287 20.792 296.863 22.976 296.863 25.4C296.863 27.824 296.287 30.02 295.135 31.988C293.983 33.932 292.399 35.456 290.383 36.56C288.391 37.664 286.147 38.216 283.651 38.216ZM283.651 35.84C285.643 35.84 287.443 35.396 289.051 34.508C290.659 33.596 291.919 32.348 292.831 30.764C293.743 29.156 294.199 27.368 294.199 25.4C294.199 23.432 293.743 21.656 292.831 20.072C291.919 18.464 290.659 17.216 289.051 16.328C287.443 15.416 285.643 14.96 283.651 14.96C281.659 14.96 279.847 15.416 278.215 16.328C276.607 17.216 275.335 18.464 274.399 20.072C273.487 21.656 273.031 23.432 273.031 25.4C273.031 27.368 273.487 29.156 274.399 30.764C275.335 32.348 276.607 33.596 278.215 34.508C279.847 35.396 281.659 35.84 283.651 35.84ZM323.894 12.8V38H321.698L305.498 17.552V38H302.834V12.8H305.03L321.266 33.248V12.8H323.894Z" fill="#efefec"/>
      <path class="line2" d="M321.11 49L4.60998 49" stroke="#efefec" stroke-width="2.89" stroke-linecap="square"/>
      <line class="line3" x1="4.445" y1="1.555" x2="320.665" y2="1.555" stroke="#efefec" stroke-width="2.89" stroke-linecap="square"/>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to get both of the lines to expand from the middle all the
> way to the end.

Instead of animating `stroke-dashoffset`, use animation `stroke-dasharray`

The length of each horizontal line of the logo is `316.2px`

```
@keyframes dash {
  from {stroke-dasharray:0,158 0,158 }
  to {stroke-dasharray:0,0,316,0;}
```

```css
.line3, .line2 {
  stroke-dasharray:316.2;
    stroke-dashoffset:316.2;
    animation: dash 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {stroke-dasharray:0,158.1 0,158.1 }
  to {stroke-dasharray:0,0,316.2,0;}
  
}
```

```html
<svg width="324" height="51" viewBox="0 0 324 51" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path id="DENNIS PRESTON" d="M0.104 12.8H10.364C13.028 12.8 15.38 13.34 17.42 14.42C19.46 15.476 21.044 16.964 22.172 18.884C23.3 20.78 23.864 22.952 23.864 25.4C23.864 27.848 23.3 30.032 22.172 31.952C21.044 33.848 19.46 35.336 17.42 36.416C15.38 37.472 13.028 38 10.364 38H0.104V12.8ZM10.22 35.696C12.428 35.696 14.36 35.264 16.016 34.4C17.672 33.512 18.956 32.3 19.868 30.764C20.78 29.204 21.236 27.416 21.236 25.4C21.236 23.384 20.78 21.608 19.868 20.072C18.956 18.512 17.672 17.3 16.016 16.436C14.36 15.548 12.428 15.104 10.22 15.104H2.768V35.696H10.22ZM47.6662 35.696V38H29.8462V12.8H47.1262V15.104H32.5102V24.068H45.5422V26.336H32.5102V35.696H47.6662ZM74.9882 12.8V38H72.7922L56.5922 17.552V38H53.9282V12.8H56.1242L72.3602 33.248V12.8H74.9882ZM104.273 12.8V38H102.077L85.8774 17.552V38H83.2134V12.8H85.4094L101.645 33.248V12.8H104.273ZM112.499 12.8H115.163V38H112.499V12.8ZM130.31 38.216C128.438 38.216 126.638 37.916 124.91 37.316C123.206 36.716 121.886 35.924 120.95 34.94L121.994 32.888C122.906 33.8 124.118 34.544 125.63 35.12C127.142 35.672 128.702 35.948 130.31 35.948C132.566 35.948 134.258 35.54 135.386 34.724C136.514 33.884 137.078 32.804 137.078 31.484C137.078 30.476 136.766 29.672 136.142 29.072C135.542 28.472 134.798 28.016 133.91 27.704C133.022 27.368 131.786 27.008 130.202 26.624C128.306 26.144 126.794 25.688 125.666 25.256C124.538 24.8 123.566 24.116 122.75 23.204C121.958 22.292 121.562 21.056 121.562 19.496C121.562 18.224 121.898 17.072 122.57 16.04C123.242 14.984 124.274 14.144 125.666 13.52C127.058 12.896 128.786 12.584 130.85 12.584C132.29 12.584 133.694 12.788 135.062 13.196C136.454 13.58 137.654 14.12 138.662 14.816L137.762 16.94C136.706 16.244 135.578 15.728 134.378 15.392C133.178 15.032 132.002 14.852 130.85 14.852C128.642 14.852 126.974 15.284 125.846 16.148C124.742 16.988 124.19 18.08 124.19 19.424C124.19 20.432 124.49 21.248 125.09 21.872C125.714 22.472 126.482 22.94 127.394 23.276C128.33 23.588 129.578 23.936 131.138 24.32C132.986 24.776 134.474 25.232 135.602 25.688C136.754 26.12 137.726 26.792 138.518 27.704C139.31 28.592 139.706 29.804 139.706 31.34C139.706 32.612 139.358 33.776 138.662 34.832C137.99 35.864 136.946 36.692 135.53 37.316C134.114 37.916 132.374 38.216 130.31 38.216ZM164.364 12.8C167.58 12.8 170.1 13.568 171.924 15.104C173.748 16.64 174.66 18.752 174.66 21.44C174.66 24.128 173.748 26.24 171.924 27.776C170.1 29.288 167.58 30.044 164.364 30.044H157.596V38H154.932V12.8H164.364ZM164.292 27.704C166.788 27.704 168.696 27.164 170.016 26.084C171.336 24.98 171.996 23.432 171.996 21.44C171.996 19.4 171.336 17.84 170.016 16.76C168.696 15.656 166.788 15.104 164.292 15.104H157.596V27.704H164.292ZM197.628 38L191.868 29.9C191.22 29.972 190.548 30.008 189.852 30.008H183.084V38H180.42V12.8H189.852C193.068 12.8 195.588 13.568 197.412 15.104C199.236 16.64 200.148 18.752 200.148 21.44C200.148 23.408 199.644 25.076 198.636 26.444C197.652 27.788 196.236 28.76 194.388 29.36L200.544 38H197.628ZM189.78 27.74C192.276 27.74 194.184 27.188 195.504 26.084C196.824 24.98 197.484 23.432 197.484 21.44C197.484 19.4 196.824 17.84 195.504 16.76C194.184 15.656 192.276 15.104 189.78 15.104H183.084V27.74H189.78ZM224.256 35.696V38H206.436V12.8H223.716V15.104H209.1V24.068H222.132V26.336H209.1V35.696H224.256ZM237.466 38.216C235.594 38.216 233.794 37.916 232.066 37.316C230.362 36.716 229.042 35.924 228.106 34.94L229.15 32.888C230.062 33.8 231.274 34.544 232.786 35.12C234.298 35.672 235.858 35.948 237.466 35.948C239.722 35.948 241.414 35.54 242.542 34.724C243.67 33.884 244.234 32.804 244.234 31.484C244.234 30.476 243.922 29.672 243.298 29.072C242.698 28.472 241.954 28.016 241.066 27.704C240.178 27.368 238.942 27.008 237.358 26.624C235.462 26.144 233.95 25.688 232.822 25.256C231.694 24.8 230.722 24.116 229.906 23.204C229.114 22.292 228.718 21.056 228.718 19.496C228.718 18.224 229.054 17.072 229.726 16.04C230.398 14.984 231.43 14.144 232.822 13.52C234.214 12.896 235.942 12.584 238.006 12.584C239.446 12.584 240.85 12.788 242.218 13.196C243.61 13.58 244.81 14.12 245.818 14.816L244.918 16.94C243.862 16.244 242.734 15.728 241.534 15.392C240.334 15.032 239.158 14.852 238.006 14.852C235.798 14.852 234.13 15.284 233.002 16.148C231.898 16.988 231.346 18.08 231.346 19.424C231.346 20.432 231.646 21.248 232.246 21.872C232.87 22.472 233.638 22.94 234.55 23.276C235.486 23.588 236.734 23.936 238.294 24.32C240.142 24.776 241.63 25.232 242.758 25.688C243.91 26.12 244.882 26.792 245.674 27.704C246.466 28.592 246.862 29.804 246.862 31.34C246.862 32.612 246.514 33.776 245.818 34.832C245.146 35.864 244.102 36.692 242.686 37.316C241.27 37.916 239.53 38.216 237.466 38.216ZM257.211 15.104H248.355V12.8H268.731V15.104H259.875V38H257.211V15.104ZM283.651 38.216C281.155 38.216 278.887 37.664 276.847 36.56C274.831 35.432 273.247 33.896 272.095 31.952C270.967 30.008 270.403 27.824 270.403 25.4C270.403 22.976 270.967 20.792 272.095 18.848C273.247 16.904 274.831 15.38 276.847 14.276C278.887 13.148 281.155 12.584 283.651 12.584C286.147 12.584 288.391 13.136 290.383 14.24C292.399 15.344 293.983 16.88 295.135 18.848C296.287 20.792 296.863 22.976 296.863 25.4C296.863 27.824 296.287 30.02 295.135 31.988C293.983 33.932 292.399 35.456 290.383 36.56C288.391 37.664 286.147 38.216 283.651 38.216ZM283.651 35.84C285.643 35.84 287.443 35.396 289.051 34.508C290.659 33.596 291.919 32.348 292.831 30.764C293.743 29.156 294.199 27.368 294.199 25.4C294.199 23.432 293.743 21.656 292.831 20.072C291.919 18.464 290.659 17.216 289.051 16.328C287.443 15.416 285.643 14.96 283.651 14.96C281.659 14.96 279.847 15.416 278.215 16.328C276.607 17.216 275.335 18.464 274.399 20.072C273.487 21.656 273.031 23.432 273.031 25.4C273.031 27.368 273.487 29.156 274.399 30.764C275.335 32.348 276.607 33.596 278.215 34.508C279.847 35.396 281.659 35.84 283.651 35.84ZM323.894 12.8V38H321.698L305.498 17.552V38H302.834V12.8H305.03L321.266 33.248V12.8H323.894Z" fill="#efefec"/>
      <path class="line2" d="M321.11 49L4.60998 49" stroke="#efefec" stroke-width="2.89" stroke-linecap="square"/>
      <line class="line3" x1="4.445" y1="1.555" x2="320.665" y2="1.555" stroke="#efefec" stroke-width="2.89" stroke-linecap="square"/>
    </svg>
```

### Update

OP comment:

> but i am trying to remove the 4 dots on the corners that apparently
> are where the lines begun

The reason for the appearance of points in the corners was the attribute `stroke-linecap ="square"`

Other line attributes have also been slightly changed.

```css
.line2, .line3 {
  stroke-dasharray:316.5;
    stroke-dashoffset:316.5;
    animation: dash 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {stroke-dasharray:0,158.25 0,158.25 }
  to {stroke-dasharray:0,0,316.5,0;}
  
}
```

```html
<svg width="324" height="51" viewBox="0 0 324 51"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
      <path id="DENNIS PRESTON" d="M0.104 12.8H10.364C13.028 12.8 15.38 13.34 17.42 14.42C19.46 15.476 21.044 16.964 22.172 18.884C23.3 20.78 23.864 22.952 23.864 25.4C23.864 27.848 23.3 30.032 22.172 31.952C21.044 33.848 19.46 35.336 17.42 36.416C15.38 37.472 13.028 38 10.364 38H0.104V12.8ZM10.22 35.696C12.428 35.696 14.36 35.264 16.016 34.4C17.672 33.512 18.956 32.3 19.868 30.764C20.78 29.204 21.236 27.416 21.236 25.4C21.236 23.384 20.78 21.608 19.868 20.072C18.956 18.512 17.672 17.3 16.016 16.436C14.36 15.548 12.428 15.104 10.22 15.104H2.768V35.696H10.22ZM47.6662 35.696V38H29.8462V12.8H47.1262V15.104H32.5102V24.068H45.5422V26.336H32.5102V35.696H47.6662ZM74.9882 12.8V38H72.7922L56.5922 17.552V38H53.9282V12.8H56.1242L72.3602 33.248V12.8H74.9882ZM104.273 12.8V38H102.077L85.8774 17.552V38H83.2134V12.8H85.4094L101.645 33.248V12.8H104.273ZM112.499 12.8H115.163V38H112.499V12.8ZM130.31 38.216C128.438 38.216 126.638 37.916 124.91 37.316C123.206 36.716 121.886 35.924 120.95 34.94L121.994 32.888C122.906 33.8 124.118 34.544 125.63 35.12C127.142 35.672 128.702 35.948 130.31 35.948C132.566 35.948 134.258 35.54 135.386 34.724C136.514 33.884 137.078 32.804 137.078 31.484C137.078 30.476 136.766 29.672 136.142 29.072C135.542 28.472 134.798 28.016 133.91 27.704C133.022 27.368 131.786 27.008 130.202 26.624C128.306 26.144 126.794 25.688 125.666 25.256C124.538 24.8 123.566 24.116 122.75 23.204C121.958 22.292 121.562 21.056 121.562 19.496C121.562 18.224 121.898 17.072 122.57 16.04C123.242 14.984 124.274 14.144 125.666 13.52C127.058 12.896 128.786 12.584 130.85 12.584C132.29 12.584 133.694 12.788 135.062 13.196C136.454 13.58 137.654 14.12 138.662 14.816L137.762 16.94C136.706 16.244 135.578 15.728 134.378 15.392C133.178 15.032 132.002 14.852 130.85 14.852C128.642 14.852 126.974 15.284 125.846 16.148C124.742 16.988 124.19 18.08 124.19 19.424C124.19 20.432 124.49 21.248 125.09 21.872C125.714 22.472 126.482 22.94 127.394 23.276C128.33 23.588 129.578 23.936 131.138 24.32C132.986 24.776 134.474 25.232 135.602 25.688C136.754 26.12 137.726 26.792 138.518 27.704C139.31 28.592 139.706 29.804 139.706 31.34C139.706 32.612 139.358 33.776 138.662 34.832C137.99 35.864 136.946 36.692 135.53 37.316C134.114 37.916 132.374 38.216 130.31 38.216ZM164.364 12.8C167.58 12.8 170.1 13.568 171.924 15.104C173.748 16.64 174.66 18.752 174.66 21.44C174.66 24.128 173.748 26.24 171.924 27.776C170.1 29.288 167.58 30.044 164.364 30.044H157.596V38H154.932V12.8H164.364ZM164.292 27.704C166.788 27.704 168.696 27.164 170.016 26.084C171.336 24.98 171.996 23.432 171.996 21.44C171.996 19.4 171.336 17.84 170.016 16.76C168.696 15.656 166.788 15.104 164.292 15.104H157.596V27.704H164.292ZM197.628 38L191.868 29.9C191.22 29.972 190.548 30.008 189.852 30.008H183.084V38H180.42V12.8H189.852C193.068 12.8 195.588 13.568 197.412 15.104C199.236 16.64 200.148 18.752 200.148 21.44C200.148 23.408 199.644 25.076 198.636 26.444C197.652 27.788 196.236 28.76 194.388 29.36L200.544 38H197.628ZM189.78 27.74C192.276 27.74 194.184 27.188 195.504 26.084C196.824 24.98 197.484 23.432 197.484 21.44C197.484 19.4 196.824 17.84 195.504 16.76C194.184 15.656 192.276 15.104 189.78 15.104H183.084V27.74H189.78ZM224.256 35.696V38H206.436V12.8H223.716V15.104H209.1V24.068H222.132V26.336H209.1V35.696H224.256ZM237.466 38.216C235.594 38.216 233.794 37.916 232.066 37.316C230.362 36.716 229.042 35.924 228.106 34.94L229.15 32.888C230.062 33.8 231.274 34.544 232.786 35.12C234.298 35.672 235.858 35.948 237.466 35.948C239.722 35.948 241.414 35.54 242.542 34.724C243.67 33.884 244.234 32.804 244.234 31.484C244.234 30.476 243.922 29.672 243.298 29.072C242.698 28.472 241.954 28.016 241.066 27.704C240.178 27.368 238.942 27.008 237.358 26.624C235.462 26.144 233.95 25.688 232.822 25.256C231.694 24.8 230.722 24.116 229.906 23.204C229.114 22.292 228.718 21.056 228.718 19.496C228.718 18.224 229.054 17.072 229.726 16.04C230.398 14.984 231.43 14.144 232.822 13.52C234.214 12.896 235.942 12.584 238.006 12.584C239.446 12.584 240.85 12.788 242.218 13.196C243.61 13.58 244.81 14.12 245.818 14.816L244.918 16.94C243.862 16.244 242.734 15.728 241.534 15.392C240.334 15.032 239.158 14.852 238.006 14.852C235.798 14.852 234.13 15.284 233.002 16.148C231.898 16.988 231.346 18.08 231.346 19.424C231.346 20.432 231.646 21.248 232.246 21.872C232.87 22.472 233.638 22.94 234.55 23.276C235.486 23.588 236.734 23.936 238.294 24.32C240.142 24.776 241.63 25.232 242.758 25.688C243.91 26.12 244.882 26.792 245.674 27.704C246.466 28.592 246.862 29.804 246.862 31.34C246.862 32.612 246.514 33.776 245.818 34.832C245.146 35.864 244.102 36.692 242.686 37.316C241.27 37.916 239.53 38.216 237.466 38.216ZM257.211 15.104H248.355V12.8H268.731V15.104H259.875V38H257.211V15.104ZM283.651 38.216C281.155 38.216 278.887 37.664 276.847 36.56C274.831 35.432 273.247 33.896 272.095 31.952C270.967 30.008 270.403 27.824 270.403 25.4C270.403 22.976 270.967 20.792 272.095 18.848C273.247 16.904 274.831 15.38 276.847 14.276C278.887 13.148 281.155 12.584 283.651 12.584C286.147 12.584 288.391 13.136 290.383 14.24C292.399 15.344 293.983 16.88 295.135 18.848C296.287 20.792 296.863 22.976 296.863 25.4C296.863 27.824 296.287 30.02 295.135 31.988C293.983 33.932 292.399 35.456 290.383 36.56C288.391 37.664 286.147 38.216 283.651 38.216ZM283.651 35.84C285.643 35.84 287.443 35.396 289.051 34.508C290.659 33.596 291.919 32.348 292.831 30.764C293.743 29.156 294.199 27.368 294.199 25.4C294.199 23.432 293.743 21.656 292.831 20.072C291.919 18.464 290.659 17.216 289.051 16.328C287.443 15.416 285.643 14.96 283.651 14.96C281.659 14.96 279.847 15.416 278.215 16.328C276.607 17.216 275.335 18.464 274.399 20.072C273.487 21.656 273.031 23.432 273.031 25.4C273.031 27.368 273.487 29.156 274.399 30.764C275.335 32.348 276.607 33.596 278.215 34.508C279.847 35.396 281.659 35.84 283.651 35.84ZM323.894 12.8V38H321.698L305.498 17.552V38H302.834V12.8H305.03L321.266 33.248V12.8H323.894Z" fill="#efefec"/>
      <path class="line2" d="M321.11 49L4.60998 49" stroke="silver" stroke-width="3" />
      <line class="line3" x1="4.5" y1="1.555" x2="321" y2="1.555" stroke="silver" stroke-width="3"  />
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandr_TT, very useful. Not trying to be ungrateful or anything, but i am trying to remove the 4 dots on the corners that apparently are where the lines begun.
Besides that are perfect actually.

Comment: @fuesto
I do not see these four points, maybe take a screenshot and indicate the location of the points with an arrow

Comment: @fuesto Thanks. I'll try to remove these dots.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful. I will study your solution and apparently I did vote and accept the answer ;)